# Cumulative count for a column using R

Tags: r

I got data like this

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), drug_1 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), drug_2 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L
))
```

I would like to get the cumulative count of each column for each id and get the data like this

```
structure(list(id2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), drug_1_b = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2), drug_2_b = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
0, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a cumulative sum with `cumsum`.

To split data.frame into subsets, you can use `split` and then lapply `cumsum` over the list of the data.frames and again over the list of the columns, or you can use the `ave` function which does exactly that:

```
data = structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), drug_1 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), drug_2 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L
))
data[-1] = ave(data[-1], data$id, FUN=cumsum)
```

edit:
I assumed that the cumulative sum is requested (as per instructions) and that there is a mistake in the example data. If the example data is correct, then the condition is *If the count is zero, don't do cumulative sum and leave at zero* or `ifelse(x == 0, 0, cumsum(x))` (as per @r2evans). However, this construct doesn't work when applied for the data.frame. A more complex helper function is required:

```
data[-1] = ave(data[-1], data$id, FUN=function(x){
    y = cumsum(x)
    y[x == 0] = 0
    y
    })
```

We can now compare it with the requested (renamed) data:

```
result = structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), drug_1 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2), drug_2 = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
0, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
identical(data, result)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this assigns non-zero values to the `0` rows, which is not in the intended output.

Comment: Then it is not a cumulative count as requested by the OP.

I will edit the answer to include the "If zero, then ignore"

Comment: Inferring from the expected output, it *is* a cumulative sum/count ... of non-0 entries. (The OP might be worded better to reflect this constraint.)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** Simplified the solution after reading r2evans' approach.

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("drug"), 
                ~ifelse(.x == 0, 0, cumsum(.x)))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 12 x 3
      id drug_1 drug_2
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1      0      0
 2     1      0      1
 3     1      0      2
 4     1      0      3
 5     1      0      4
 6     1      1      0
 7     1      2      5
 8     2      0      0
 9     2      0      0
10     2      1      1
11     2      0      0
12     2      2      2
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R,

```r
ave(df$drug_2, df$id, FUN = function(z) ifelse(z == 0, z, cumsum(z)))
#  [1] 0 1 2 3 4 0 5 0 0 1 0 2
```

Comment: Turns out, I was overthinking the problem... No need for `lag`-functions here...

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
# Resolve the names of vectors we want to cumulatively sum:
# drug_vec_names => character vector
drug_vec_names <- grep( "^drug\\_", colnames(df), value = TRUE)

# Resolve the names of vectors we want to keep: 
# not_drug_vec_names => character vector
not_drug_vec_names <- names(df)[!(names(df) %in% drug_vec_names)]

# Calculate the result: res => data.frame
res <- setNames(
  cbind(
    df[,not_drug_vec_names],
    replace(
      ave(
        df[,drug_vec_names], 
        df[,not_drug_vec_names],
        FUN = cumsum
      ),
      df[,drug_vec_names] == 0,
      0
    )
  ),
  c(not_drug_vec_names, drug_vec_names)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have binary values (1/0) in `drug` columns, you can multiply the cumulative sum with itself to get 0 for 0 values.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('drug'), ~cumsum(.) * .)) %>%
  ungroup

#      id drug_1 drug_2
#   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     1      0      0
# 2     1      0      1
# 3     1      0      2
# 4     1      0      3
# 5     1      0      4
# 6     1      1      0
# 7     1      2      5
# 8     2      0      0
# 9     2      0      0
#10     2      1      1
#11     2      0      0
#12     2      2      2
```